# Calculatig $\zeta (0)$ from $\zeta (2n)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\mathrm B_{2n}(2\pi )^{2n}}{2(2n)!}$

Tags: analysis, riemann-zeta

MathWorld and Wikipedia state that
$$\zeta (2n)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\mathrm B_{2n}(2\pi )^{2n}}{2(2n)!}$$
is valid for positive integers $n$. But the identity works for $0$ as well. Is it rigorous to use the identity to prove that $\zeta (0)=-\frac12$?

Comment: Of course, the identity is assumed to be proved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Of course it depends how you proved $\zeta (2n)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\mathrm B_{2n}(2\pi )^{2n}}{2(2n)!}, n\ge 1$.

If it is applying the residue theorem to $\lim_{N \to \infty}\int_{|z| = N} \frac{z^{-2n}}{e^z-1}dz$ then no it doesn't apply to $n=0$.

Same if it is from the Fourier series or $\pi s\cot\pi s=s\sum_k \frac1{s+k}=1-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\mathrm B_{2n}(2\pi )^{2n}}{2(2n)!}s^{2n}$.

If it is after showing the functional equation and $\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)=  (-1)^n\frac{B_n}{n!}\frac{1}{s+n-1}+O(1)$ then yes it is valid for $n=0$.

Comment: It was not by any of the two ways you describe (though it might be related to them): I proved that $\pi s\cot\pi s=1-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\mathrm B_{2n}(2\pi )^{2n}}{2(2n)!}s^{2n}$ for $|2i\pi s|\lt 1$, and $\pi s\cot\pi s=1-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \zeta (2n)s^{2n}$ for $|s^2|\lt 1$. I compared these identities to get the identity in my question. But the sum starts at $n=1$, could index shifting to $n=0$ help?

Comment: This is more or less what I meant with the Fourier series and residue theorem method, as you see it doesn't tell anything about $n=0$